# How to finding relation between input parameter and output parameter by machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I have 20 numeric input parameters (or more) and single output parameter and I have thousands of these data. I need to find the relation between input parameters and output parameter. Some input parameters might not relate to output parameter or all input parameters might not relate to output parameter. I want some magic system that can statistically calculate output parameter when I provide all input parameters and it much be better if this system also provide confident rate with output result.

What’s technique (in machine learning) that I need to use to solve this problem? I think it should be Neural network, genetic algorithm or other related thing. But I don't sure. More than that, I need to know the limitation of this technique.

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to simply define the **[regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)** problem. Which can be solved by numerous algorithms and models, not just neural networks.

- Support Vector Regression
- Neural Networks
- Linear regression (and many modifications and generalizations) using for example OLS method
- Nearest Neighbours Regression
- Decision Tree Regression
- many, many more!

Simply look for "regression methods", "regression models" etc. in particular, [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) library implements many of such methods.

Comment: Dear lejlot, I hope you don't mind my writing to you here in the comment section, I was wondering if you would be interested in this recent post on Chess SE, https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19353/understanding-alphazero your input and insights would be incredibly valuable. Look forward, best wishes.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend Genetic Programming (GP), which is genetic-based machine learning approach where the learnt model is a single mathematical expression/equation that best fits your data. Most GP packages out there come with a standard regression suite which you can run "as is" with your data, and with minimal setup costs.